# Dash long tasks via redis queue

Tags: heroku, redis, gunicorn, plotly-dash

I want to build a web app in Dash that executes a computationally expensive task on user-inputted data and returns the result in a tabular format.
On the front end side, I have a Dash callback that updates Dash components based on inputs from Dash components, e.g.:

```
from rq import Queue
from worker import conn
import time

# redis connection to execute tasks in the background
q = Queue(connection=conn,job_timeout='3m')
@app.callback(
    [Output('table-columns', 'columns'),
     Output('table-columns', 'data'),],
    [Input('upload', 'contents'),
     Input('launch-expensive-job-button', 'n_clicks')],
     )

def expensive_task(contents, n_clicks_launch):
    df = q.enqueue(expensive_function, contents).result
    while df is None:
        time.sleep(2)
    return [{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df.columns], df.to_dict("rows")
```

I am using Redis queue to run the task in the background. As soon as the result is updated in the df variable (Redis convention is result None during processing), I am returning it to the client. The problem is that my deployment platform does not allow front-end jobs to run for too long. Therefore, even if I am sending the job to the backend, I have to find a way to make the Dash app listen to any updates on the variable df.

I am sure the solution is somewhere accessible, but I am too much of a newbie to find it. Happy to be pointed to some documentation where I could find my way around.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the `Interval` component (documentation [here](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/interval)). It triggers a client update at a regular interval, e.g. once per second. The callback would be along the lines of,

```
...
Interval(id='trigger', interval=1000)  # must be in the app layout
...

@app.callback(Output(...), [Input('trigger', 'n_intervals')])
def poll_update(n_intervals):
    # check status of redis here and update the output accordingly
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, the ```Interval``` component is definitely the way to go. Moving forward with that, could you suggest a way to make the callback with the ```Interval``` component listen to the updates from the df variable, other than making the variable global? I am currently still obliged to store df locally since it is quite a large dataset, so it would be great if I would be able to transfer it directly to the callback. Many thanks!